# xxxxx is a namespace but is used like a Type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue that seems to give a large number of hits when searching on SO however every single instance I have read is clear that the poster actually is creating a namespace using a name they then go on to use again as a Class etc.

I have an instance where I cannot find any reference to the namespace it claims I am mis-using.

I am using VS 2017 co-writing a .net core 2 app and getting the above issue.  The strange thing is that if I push the code to TFS and my colleague then pulls it down he does not get the issue.  If I wipe my copy and pull down a fresh copy myself I still get the issue.

ChangeFormViewModel.cs

```
using ChangeRequestForm_Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChangeRequestForm_Web.ViewModels
{
    public class ChangeFormViewModel
    {
        public ChangeRequest ChangeRequest { get; set; }
        public ChangeProfile ChangeProfile { get; set; }

        public List<ChangeDataItem> ChangeDataItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The offending line is;

```
public ChangeRequest ChangeRequest { get; set; }
```

ChangeRequest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace ChangeRequestForm_Data.Models
{
    public class ChangeRequest : BaseEntity
    {
        public string ChangeTitle { get; set; }
        public bool ChangeSubmitted { get; set; }
        public bool ChangeCompleted { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have checked my installation of VS and verified that I am also using the same version as my colleague.  This has occured over two different projects now.

EDIT: If I use ChangeRequestForm_Data.Models.ChangeRequest this works and is in fact how I got around the issue in the previous project.  When my colleague then pulls my changes he then gets highlighting within VS suggesting it could be optimised as the full reference is un-neccessary.

Comment: Did you try fully qualified name?  public  ChangeRequestForm_Data.Models.ChangeRequest ChangeRequest { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, that resolves the problem.

Comment: I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use fully qualified name

```
public ChangeRequestForm_Data.Models.ChangeRequest ChangeRequest { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added that to original post as we used that as the solution first time around but I am told it should not be necessary.  Do you have any thoughts about why it seems to feel it is an issue for me in the first place?

Comment: maybe you have used ChangeRequest  as a namespace somewhere in your code or used namespace (example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.changerequest.aspx  )

Comment: Thats what I thought but I have combed the solution looking at all occurances of ChangeRequest, and all instances where I have declared a namespace.

Comment: and what about nuget packages and other dependencies?  Maybe just find different name for that class :)

Comment: There is very little in the project at this time so little to look through.  A different name would likely also work but again is a work around rather than a solution to an issue I am now worried will be common for me.

I'm going to rebuild my PC at some point as there is always that possiblity.  If I were to use a work around I would give the fully qualified name I think.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set namespace of project properly before model class definition, no need of fully qualified name.

Comment: Thanks, but your response adds nothing that wasn't already included in the Answer/comments above.

If you feel something was missed perhaps you could elaborate on what it is you consider to be a properly set namespace that hasn't already been mentioned?